# Cookies being rejected by ColdFusion server after hot fix(s) installed

Tags: coldfusion, session-variables, coldfusion-9

After installing the latest ColdFusion Hot Fixes, I'm having issues with existing users returning to my website and keeping them authenticated after logging in.

For example, a user returns to the website, logins in with the login form.  The login form authenticates them and sets a session.userid variables and redirects them to the member section.

Once within the member section, when they make their first click to another page application.cfc checks the current page's path, and if its in the member section and they do not have a valid session.userid, then they get redirected to the login page.

The temporary fix for every user was to tell them to clear their cookies.

I was wondering if there is any type of server side or client side code that I could deliver to my login page that could help fix this issue.

It seems that this issue is only affecting users that had previously been to the website prior to the server update.  New visitors are not affected.

Also, I felt people may ask: I have the following setting in my application.cfc:
this.setDomainCookies = "Yes";

I also setup canonical url.  any traffic to "website.com" automatically gets directed to www.website.com.

Comment: So are you setting/reading a cookie or are you using session variables?  Which HotFix did you install that you believe is causing this?

Comment: It sounds like he is using SESSION variables not cookies. Try using the CLIENT variable instead of SESSION variables to keep user data.

Comment: I'm using a session variable for login.  I've come across this issue before on a small scale, a user here to there, but I had previously attributed it to the setDomaincookies="yes/no".  Now, its affecting every site on the server.

Comment: Are you using J2EE session variables? [See this post](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4537467)

Comment: No, not using J2EE session variables.  Ran into issues in a past application with them turned on.

Comment: What HotFix did you apply?

Comment: APSB13-13, for 9.0.1, Win2008r2

Comment: I'm finding that if I use:
    <cfcookie name="CFID" value="" expires="NOW" />
    <cfcookie name="CFTOKEN" value="" expires="NOW" />
on a login page, that those users who had the issue are working OK.  This may be my temporary fix.

Comment: This is probably due to the session fixation change (see Miguel-F's link). CF will now ignore any existing CFID/CFTOKEN cookies and always generate new values to prevent hijacking, but the mis-match if the cookies do exist can cause session loss. See also http://cfsimplicity.com/4/coldfusion-security-hotfix-changes-session-behaviour

Comment: I believe that answers the question, please post that as answer so I can make it complete.  Also, am I interpreting it correctly that the fix used was to place the cookie settings onSessionStart?